# Fitting Coefficients to Data and Function using Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

I have to calculate the coefficients (c1-c9) of the function below, while both temperatures(to,tc) and the solution (y) is given through measured data at different points. I tried to solve it with numpy.linalg.solv but it raises a Singular Matrix error, which I am not sure how to avoid.

```
 c[0] + c[[0]]*to[0] + c[[1]]*tc[0] + c[3]*to[0]^2 + c[4]*to[0]*tc[0] + c[5]*tc[0]^2 + c[6]*to[0]^3 + c[7]*tc[0]*to[0]^2 + c[8]*to[0]*tc[0]^2 + c[9]*tc[0]^3 = y[0]
```

Could someone give me a clue or a solution to how this problem can be solved with Python? This is my code so far

```
import numpy as np

to1 = 10
tc1 = 30
y1  = 148450
to2 = 5
tc2 = 30
y2  = 124955
to3 = 0
tc3 = 30
y3  = 104596
to4 = -5
tc4 = 30
y4  = 86964
to5 = -10
tc5 = 30
y5  = 71704

a = np.array([[1,to1,tc1, to1**2, to1*tc1], [1,to2,tc2,to2**2, to2*tc2],[1,to3,tc3,to3**2, to3*tc3],[1,to4,tc4,to4**2, to4*tc4],[1,to5,tc5,to5**2, to5*tc5]])
b = np.array([y1,y2,y3,y4,y5])
x = np.linalg.solve(a, b)
print x
```

Comment: Do you know what a singular matrix is and why it's an error?

Comment: Could you please post the code above into your question.  It's difficult to read as a comment.

Comment: done, and i have read what wikipedia tells me about singular matrix. to be honest, i didnt understand it completly

Comment: I tried to solve one part of the equation so far, to see if it works itself out, but it didnt.

Comment: A singular matrix is one that has a determinant equal to zero.  If you do `np.linalg.det(a)`, you'll see that it's zero.  See, for example, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93186/solving-systems-of-linear-equations-when-matrix-of-coefficients-is-singular

Comment: does this mean, that I cant solve the problem with this function, because it has to be a square matrix and it will always resolve in this error?

Comment: You showed us a cubic function of `to` and `tc`, with 10 parameters to estimate, and then some code where you try to estimate the 5 parameters of an incomplete quadratic function of `to` and `tc`.  Could you please tell us  what is your question really about?

Comment: like i said, i just tried if the function works for a part of the equilation. it doesn't. so i didn't tried to complete the equilation.

Comment: It seems that you need to understand the math behind the Python functions better.  There are many, many discussions of these issues all over the place (most are not Python specific).  In the end, you are running into a math problem and not a programming problem, and SO isn't a good place to discuss it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your Problem

In all your data points you have `tc=30`!

When you try to fit your data with a function of `to, tc` the algorithm is telling you (with the only language that it knows, the language of linear algebra) that you cannot estimate the variability of `y` as a function of `tc` when there is no variation of `tc` in your data set.

## How to correct your problem

Have more data point, with different values of both the independent variables, and as far as it is possible use a least squares approach using ALL the data points that you can collect (I mean, 10 parameters to estimate? use tens or hundreds of data points).  This part of the answer is independent of the programming language that you want to use: have more data.

Comment: changing the values of tc to something different doesnt change the Error Message. Allthough it has to be possible to be calculatable wether value the variables have. I got plenty of datapoints. But the methode np.linalg.solve(a, b) needs, as i understand it, a cubic matrix. so trough it all it can not calculate with more? or am i wrong? 
Further is a least square approach capable of fitting my data into the function i posted on top?

Comment: No, it cannot be calculated. Say you have a simple linear model `y=1+bx` and two data points `(x=5,y=7)`, `(x=5,y=9`), first equation is `a + 5b = 7`, second one is `a + 5b = 9`... you cannot solve this system of two equations in two unknowns because IT IS ONLY ONE EQUATION that you are trying to use to compute two parameters.  Your formulation, where you have NO DEPENDENCY on `tc`, is the same as above, some of the equations are essentially the same, and this, in the language of linear algebra, is called "you have a singular matrix", i.e., the error that `numpy` keeps reporting to you.

Comment: You can use a least squares approach with your data, but what you will obtain is just some big warning about rank deficiency (silenced by default in numpy) and the parameter for the terms that are independent of `tc`.  If you know, on theoretical grounds, that you have a dependency on `tc` the ONLY thing that you can do is having data points for different values of `tc`,  BTW my suggestion in the answer is to use more data points than parameters and using a least squares estimate, if I wasn't clear enough in my statement.

Comment: hey, that was a great answer. now i understand the problem and i see how dump i was. thanks for this input

Comment: In my 1st comment I wrote `y=1+bx`: a typo, I meant `y=a+bx` of course... I'm really sorry for the possible misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you that the matrix is *singular*, thus it is rank-deficient and thus the determinant is zero. You can check this with:

```
print np.linalg.matrix_rank(a)
```

which gives 3 instead of 5. A very nice explanation of what this means can be found in this question/answer:

[What is rank-deficiency and how to deal with it](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it)

You can however, find a least-squares solution that is a "good-fit" -- though as mentioned is no unique solution to the matrix given since some rows are linearly dependent on each other.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But there is no least square methode that can fit a function identically to the form of equilation i need, am i right? As I assume, you are better at mathemetic than me. Have you any clue what I should search for?